# Как в GitHub-е обращаться с зависимыми PR?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

Сделал PR в GitHub репозиторий со множеством изменений. Например, изменения названий функций, используя другую name convention. PR стоит открытый. Теперь я хочу сделать другой PR, который реализует какую-то фичу. Он зависит от первого PR, т.к. удобнее использовать новые названия и при мерже автору не надо будет конфликты резолвить. Если просто сделать ветку от ветки первого PR, то в ревью второго PR-а будут также коммиты первого, т.к. он ещё не был замержен в мастер. Более того, после мержа в мастер первого PR, надо будет делать ребейз второго PR снова на master, общие коммиты автоматом не удаляются.

Как в гитхабе лучше всего указать зависимость между PR? Или это никак не поддерживается и лучший вариант ждать мержа первого PR, чтобы получить максимально чистую историю?

Comment: удалить первый PR и вместо него создать новый, где обе Ваши доработки будут объединены в одну

Comment: @ESkri так я специально пример привёл конкретный, чтобы показать что это 2 совсем разных изменения: рефакторинг и новая фича. Разве правильно их в один PR добавлять?

Comment: не бойтесь, всё ненужное из вашего объединённого PR автор выкинет сам )))

Comment: разные изменения (рефакторинг и новая фича) нужно разбросать по разным коммитам, но все эти коммиты подать как один PR.

Comment: @ESkri допустим, maintainer согласен с первым коммитом, но не согласен со вторым. Если бы это были разные PR, то он мог быть смержить первый и дать ревью на второй. А так весь PR будет простаивать, пока не исправятся все подPRы в нём.

Comment: Сделать второй PR не в основную ветку, а в ветку первого PR в виде драфта. Тогда GH будет показывать только полезные изменения и не даст случайно его замержить.
Примеры https://github.com/alexeyten/Iosevka/pull/1, https://github.com/alexeyten/Iosevka/pull/3

Comment: @AlexeyTen а так можно вообще? В плане эта первая ветка же существует в моём форке, а не у апстрима, а PRы предлагают ветки апстрима на выбор вроде.

Comment: В PR можно выбрать в какой репозиторий https://i.stack.imgur.com/01SqK.png

Comment: @AlexeyTen то есть несмотря на то что ветка первого PR-а не была вмержена в репозиторий, в который хочу сделать PR, всё равно в эту ветку можно будет сделать другой PR и этот другой PR будет отображаться именно у желаемого репозитория, не у моего форка? Если да, то это то, что надо, можете дать ответ.

Comment: Нет, это будет PR в твоём репозитории, т.е. владелец основного его никак не увидит. Но хотя бы будет место где на код можно посмотреть и покомментировать…

Comment: @AlexeyTen ну вот, а хотелось бы 2 PR в основном репе, хотя можно ссылку в первом дать мол "я уже второй PR сделал тут, мержь быстрее!" :)

Comment: Кое-что из того что нужно решает https://graphite.dev/stacking

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA картинки выглядят правильно :) А в итоге что он делает на уровне гитхаба? Второй PR это драфт в мастер с 2 коммитами? Просто делает это одной командой, а не ручками? То есть облегчает работу мне, но не maintainer-у, который всё равно видит кучу PR-ов с повторяющимися коммитами? Я правильно понял?

Comment: Не могу сказать, так как с github не использовал, а только с gitlab, в котором как раз управление PR-ами не поддреживается. Использую его ради stacking-а и для этого он очень удобен.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA в любом случае спасибо за наводку.

Comment: Я понимаю, как можно сделать удобно в graphite (не знаю сделано ли) для одного репозитория - PR должен быть в ту ветку, от которой отпочковались как писал выше Alexey Ten. graphite может автоматически менять базу для всех зависимых PR после слияния (как он это делает локально для веток). Как это может быть решено в случае нескольких репозиториев - не ясно. Разве что разрешить в upstream тоже создавать ветки специально для отслеживания еще не влитых PR-ов.

Comment: `Если бы это были разные PR, то он мог быть смержить первый и дать ревью на второй` - это редкое явление, когда ваш PR принимают как есть.  чаще всего автор будет что-то исправлять (и половину выкинет), прежде чем вольёт к себе.  во время исправлений он вам напишет коммент в PR по поводу каждого вашего коммита

Comment: Ждать мерджа первого PR придется в любом случае, даже если бы пачки PR полноценно поддерживались в гитхабе. https://blog.logrocket.com/using-stacked-pull-requests-in-github/ А чтобы получить максимально чистую историю необходимо избегать фиктивных мерджей.